# ¿en un dataframe de pandas, cómo puedo recorrer toda la tabla, de forma que me quede como resultado el índice junto a la columna?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indices

Digamos que tengo estos datos

```
daticos = pd.DataFrame({"d":[1,2,3],"e":[4,5,6]},index=["a","b","c"])

print(daticos)
    d   e
a   1   4
b   2   5
c   3   6
```

Al final quiero tener una tabla así:

```
loc_daticos = pd.DataFrame(data=([["a,d","a,e"],["b,d","b,e"],["c,d","c,e"]]),index=["a","b","c"],columns=["d","e"])
print (loc_daticos)
    d     e
a   a,d  a,e
b   b,d  b,e
c   c,d  c,e
```

He intentado recorrer la matriz, pero no puedo hacer para tener la matriz con sus índices y columnas.
Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución es un doble ciclo `for` anidado.

En el primero, recorremos las filas, recuperando el indice de la fila. Luego recorremos las columnas de la fila, recuperando el nombre de la columna. Finalmente, juntamos ambas partes para formar el par "a, b".

```
import pandas as pd
daticos = pd.DataFrame({"d":[1,2,3],"e":[4,5,6]},index=["a","b","c"])
loc_daticos = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(daticos)):
    row = daticos.index.values[i]
    for j in range(len(daticos.columns)):
        col = daticos.columns[j]
        loc_daticos.at[row, col] = "%s, %s" % (row, col)

print(loc_daticos)
```

produce

```
      d     e
a  a, d  a, e
b  b, d  b, e
c  c, d  c, e
```